# .animate() function in jQuery doesn't work sliding images

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate, slideshow

Code:

```
$("#previous_image").click(function(){
  $("#images").animate({"right": "+=250px"}, "slow");
    return false;
});
```

When i run a console.log i get into the click function, so that ain't a problem. It seems my div just doesn't want to get animated.

My CSS code (SASS)

```
#images_container{
  display: block;
  margin-left: 39px;
  width: 630px;
  height: 81px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#images{
  display: block;
  width: 1500px;
  min-width: 650px;


  img{
    margin-top: 7px;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 66px;
    cursor: pointer;

    filter: url(svg/filters.svg#grayscale);
    filter: gray; /* IE6-9 */
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%); /* Google Chrome & Safari 6+ */

    transition: filter .3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: filter .3s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: filter .3s ease-in-out;
    transition: -webkit-filter .3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: -webkit-filter .3s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-filter .3s ease-in-out;

    @include transition-property(-webkit-filter);
    @include transition-duration(.3s);
    @include transition-timing-function(ease-out);

    &:hover{
      filter: none;
      -webkit-filter: grayscale(0);
    }
  }
```

Any toughts? It's freaking me out.

Cheers.
W.

Comment: are they positioned absolutely?

Comment: The img's in my #images? Nope. The #images div isn't ether.

Comment: Is that your input to SASS or what SASS generates?  Either way, it looks awful.  Surely the standardised `transition: filter .3s ease-in-out;` should come last?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't need the `+=`

Try this:

```
$("#previous_image").click(function(){
    $("#images").animate({"right": "250px"}, "slow");
    return false;
});
```

Also to use `right` and `left` you need an absolutely positioned element. In order to position something absolutely you need it's container to be position relatively.

So change your css to this:

```
#images_container{
  display: block;
  margin-left: 39px;
  width: 630px;
  height: 81px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

#images{
  display: block;
  width: 1500px;
  min-width: 650px;
  position: absolute;
}
```